# How to attach a Symfony Session with the connection object from Ratchet?

Tags: symfony, ratchet

Hi I am working in a **symfony** real time app using **Ratchet** Library, In my app I need to send some data to a specific user.And the only way to do this is to attach a symfony session object to each incoming Connection object.
I have read the doc [here](http://socketo.me/docs/sessions) but I can't understand it and how to make it work in symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://socketo.me/docs/sessions) states need to setup a **non-native** session handler to store your sessions i.e. [**in a database via PDO**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html).

Then you need to configure Ratchet to use your session handler. If you're using [ClankBundle](https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle) you can read this [documentation chapter](https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/SessionSetup.md).

Comment: I store session in memcached ,I set everything related,  but when I do : $conn->Session->get('key'); it returns Null